# What is the most effective method to input an array in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, performance, input, inputstream

I need to read an array stored in a single line in a text file.
What am doing till now is this:

```
BufferedReader in = /*hook it to the file input stream via an InputStreamReader  */
String[] input = in.readLine().split(" ");
for (int i = 0; i < input.length; i++) 
     array[i] = Integer.parseInt(input[i]);
```

Here, am using the String array unnecessarily. How can I remove this redundant step?

Comment: Is this such a catastrophic performance issue? You want to avoid using `String#split`?

Comment: Reading a file on the disk is several orders of magnitude slower than splitting a string, instantiating a String array and converting every element to an Integer. You won't gain anything significant by doing this. This would be like using running shoes to walk the 10 meters from your car to your house after a 2,000 miles trip. Premature optimization is the root of all evil. Use clean and maintainable code, and optimize only if necessary, and where it's necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can use the `InputStream` and the `Scanner` class, you can do something like:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(inputStream);
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
while(scanner.hasNext()) {
    list.add(scanner.nextInt());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
BufferedReader in = /*hook it to the file input stream via an InputStreamReader  */
String input = in.readLine();
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
List<Integer> list = new LinkedList<>(); //yours array equivalent
for (int i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
    char ch = input.charAt(i);
    if (ch == ' ') {
        list.add(Integer.parseInt(sb.toString()));
        sb.clear();
    } else {
        sb.append(ch);
    }
}
```

This way you don't need to create the redundant array. I think it's very similar to what split() method does, but it doesn't require to handle regular expressions so the performance should be much better in this case.

Comment: To improve, you could store the (int) index of the previous ' ' character (or 0 initially), instead of keeping a StringBuilder and Integer.parseInt(input.substring(previous,i)).